# Cannot find module date-fns

Tags: node.js, typescript, date-fns

I am making a nodejs project using Typescript. For my datetime manipulations, I decided to use date-fns. In their documentation, they say that typings for the library are always updated in each relase. However, I can't seem to be able to import the library itself:

```
import * as dateFns from 'date-fns';
```

It logs a `Cannot find module 'date-fns'` error.

I don't think I have any "special" configuration. I just install the library with `npm instll --save date-fns`. Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I used typescript only in Angular before. So, I might not be adept to setup a typescript environment from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

When the `module` option is set to `es6`, the `moduleResolution` option defaults to `classic`, a module resolution strategy that doesn't look in `node_modules`.  If you truly want to use `"module": "es6"`, you'll need to set `"moduleResolution": "node"`.  See [this handbook page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) for more information.  But if you are planning to run this code on node.js, you probably want to just set `"module": "commonjs"` unless you are using a separate tool to convert the ES6 modules to CommonJS.